# Upper case in ALIAS for column Name not working

Tags: sql, select, rename, alias

In the following select statement **firstname** and **Middlename** ALIAS does not appear. I want this column header to be in Uppercase.

```
SELECT  dbo.Employee.Title AS SAL,
        dbo.Employee.FirstName AS FIRSTNAME,
        dbo.Employee.MiddleName AS MIDDLENAME
FROM dbo.Employee
```

Comment: wat server are you using, for me its working fine

Comment: I am using version 9.00.5057.00 (SQL Server 2005)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried it and it works fine for me.  However, here is a suggested change to your SQL which may assist.

```
SELECT Title AS [SAL],
       FirstName AS [FIRSTNAME],
       MiddleName AS [MIDDLENAME]
FROM dbo.Employee
```

Comment: it does not work as well however the following query works with SPACE in the square brackets           SELECT Title AS [SAL ],
       FirstName AS [FIRSTNAME ],
       MiddleName AS [MIDDLENAME ]
FROM dbo.Employee

Answer (score 2):

Using double quotes works on PostgreSQL.

```
SELECT Title AS "SAL",
   FirstName AS "FIRSTNAME",
   MiddleName AS "MIDDLENAME"
FROM dbo.Employee
```